# Difference in response time of Badboy and Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, badboy

I have created a script in Badboy tool for a site. Its response time is around 95 msec.
But if i export this same script file into JMeter and run this script in JMeter then the response time is around 600msec. 
I have not made any changes in the script nor within the network.
Can anyone tell me why I am observing such difference in the response time?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Its a simple recorded script to measure the page loading time.